# Jquery Mobile + Dynamically Created pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically creating jquery mobile pages, and the only page that seems to be showing is the first one I create. All the html elements are being created. I tried using...

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page2");
```

Nothing happened

So I tried using

```
$("#page1").hide();
$("#page2").show();
```

With this code page1 would hide, but page2 would not show.

I also tried combining them

```
$("#page1").hide();
$("#page2").show();
$.mobile.changePage("#page2");
```

Strings to generate html pages inside the sections.

```
"<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"page1\" data-theme=\"b\" data-content-theme=\"b\"><h1>Page 1</h1></div>"

"<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"page2\" data-theme=\"b\" data-content-theme=\"b\"><h1>Page 2</h1></div>"
```

This is the generated html:

```
<body>
<section id="index_page" class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-b" style="display: none;"><!-- Start of home page --><div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b" data-url="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-b ui-page-active" style="min-height: 901px;"><h1>Page 1</h1></div><div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"><span class="ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>loading</h1></div></section><section id="page2" style="display: block;"><div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b"><h1>Page 2</h1></div></section>
</body>
```

Any idea what I might be missing, or if this is a bug with jquery mobile and dynamically created html?

Comment: Do you have a first page not generated that links to the generated pages ? Or do you just have a body tag and EVERY page are behind generated

Comment: I have a body tag and every page is being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the correct way to navigate from page to page programmatically is the [$.mobile.changePage();](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

- I made you an exemple [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/93ju98vn/2/)
  where you can see how to navigate from a page to another injected
  page directly or programmatically.
- I made you another exemple with just the informations you provided
  and asked for : [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/93ju98vn/3/) where
  the pages are being injected, and then displayed. But it seems to be 
  the same code you gave us. I don't know why it is not working for
  you.

  ```
  $("body").append("<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"page1\" data-theme=\"b\" data-content-theme=\"b\"><h1>Page 1</h1></div>");
  $("body").append("<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"page2\" data-theme=\"b\" data-content-theme=\"b\"><h1>Page 2</h1></div>");

  $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
  ```

  NB : the 2 last jquery lines (commented) are just here to show that
  the page navigation is still working after the first time.
- Finally, you shouldn't use the hide() and show() functions to display/hide pages.